# Prove that$f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$ where the function $f[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and one to one and such that $f(a)<f(b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let the function $f[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and one to one and such that $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $c$ be a point in the open interval $(a,b)$. Prove that$f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$.

---

Suppose the function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and one-to-one and such that $f(a)<f(b)$. So there exists a point $d$ such that $f(d)=f(\alpha)$. Let $c\in(a,b)$, then $f(a)\geq f(c)$ or $f(c)\geq f(b)$. If $f(a)= f(c)$ or $f(c)= f(b)$, that would conflict with the function is one to one. If $f(a)>f(c)$, then by the Intermediate Value theorem, there would exist an $d'\in(a,c)$ such that $f(d')=f(\alpha)$ since $f$ is continuous; however, this contradicts with $f$ is a one-to-one function; if $f(c)>f(b)$, then by the Intermediate Value theorem, there would exist an $d''\in(c,b)$ such that $f(d'')=f(\alpha)$ because $f$ is a continuous function, but contradicts with $f$ is one-to-one; in these two cases, they both conflict with the function is one to one. Therefore, $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$.

---

Can someone check my solution? I am not this is right or not because I just learn the Intermediate value theorem. Thanks.

Comment: what is $\alpha$?? You keep saying $f(d) = f(\alpha)$, but there is no $\alpha$ defined anywhere. At one point it is clear you mean $f(a)$, but then later, you say $f(\alpha)$ where you should have $f(b)$. Besides this, in the first case, you should be looking for a $d$ in $(c, b)$, and in the 2nd case, you should be looking for one in $(a, c)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair by the intermediate value theorem, there would exist a $d\in[a,b]$ such that $f(d)=\alpha$, please correct me.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?? It does no good to say that $f(d) = \alpha$ or $f(d) = f(\alpha)$ or anything else about $\alpha$ unless you have some definite $\alpha$ that you are referring to. And here, you don't. You keep saying $f(d) = f(\alpha)$ as if it had some meaning. but since you never defined a value for $\alpha$, it has no meaning at all.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see what you mean, if $f(c)<f(a)$ there exists a point $d\in (c,b)$ such that $f(d)=f(a)$; if $f(b)<f(c)$, then there exists a point $d'\in(a,c)$ such that $f(d')=f(b)$

Comment: Excellent! In the first case, you know that $f(c) < f(a) < f(b)$, and in the second that $f(a) < f(b) < f(c)$, so either way by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a value of $d$ that violates the 1-1 condition.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you so much, that helps me to understand the intermediate value theorem